# What are the notes in that circled?

Tags: sheet-music

Are the circled notes below : F, G, F and then D? I try to understand music sheet. I tried to find F notes in the song, [African Suite, Op. 35: II. Love-Song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNg7wISYyO0) but I can't find them.

[image]

Comment: Aside from the fact that there's also a G inside the left edge of the circle, yes, the notes you named are in the circle. You might edit a bit to explain more about what you're not sure about: You have indeed found some Fs; in fact, you found F *naturals*, even though there's an F sharp in the key signature.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I try to find those G, F, G, F, D in this song which is the similar song as in the picture above https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNg7wISYyO0 but I can't find them. I guess those notes are in the beginning of the song, correct?

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I'm not sure if that's what I'm searching but I'll check it out.

Comment: Oh I found the notes already. Thanks so much!

Comment: Maybe the question ought to be 'if there's an accidental in a grace note, does it affect any following same notes in the bar?'

Comment: Following my earlier comment, I feel the question is not a dupe of the quoted one, hence re-open vote.

Comment: @Tim Fair enough, but from the OP's comments and other questions, I think this question was actually about identifying which dot on which line is which letter name. I think it was "I think that's an F, but I don't hear an F in the recording, oh wait now I do." My close reason was "Identifying notes is off-topic." SnoopyKid, if you'd like to edit to make your question clearer, it might qualify for reopening if there's more to it.